# This modal code gated our wordpress resource pages just fine until it just stopped working. What could be the problem why they just don't work anymore

Tags: magnific-popup

This code has worked just fine on our wordpress pages, but it just stopped working. Its just a modal window that displays a form in a frame from Pardot, and the thank you redirect points to access=yes which allows the user to see the page without the modal. It was a handy little script to capture emails for resources but has completely stopped working. Ideas what could be the problem?

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var access = getParameterByName('access');
// if access does not = yes then display the popup
if (access != 'yes') {
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'https://www2.riskonnect.com/l/29712/2023-01-06/9nhcnv'
  },
  type: 'iframe', modal: true
});
}
});
</script>
```

Popup no longer works, so the pages are no longer gated.